# TryUpdateModel throws NullReferenceException in ASP.NET MVC 3 unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Since I upgraded from MVC 2 to MVC 3 RC, using TryUpdateModel causes a NullReferenceException. This problem only occurs when running my action method as part of a unit test. Running it on the actual server works as expected.

Here's a stack trace of the exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c_*DisplayClassc.b*_7(ValueProviderFactory
>   factory)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.TryUpdateModel[TModel](TModel
>   model, String prefix)
>   ... my own code from here on....

In case it matters, my controller has the following signature:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
}
```

My guess is that this has to do with the new way DI works in MVC3, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps there is something in terms of DI setup that is required in MVC 3, but wasn't required in MVC 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else has the same problem and finds this post:

I solved the problem generically based on Ivan Kortym's answer (thanks!), with the following piece of code in my controller base class constructor:

```
if (Request!=null && Request.Form != null && Request.Form.HasKeys() && ValueProvider == null)
{
    ValueProvider = new FormCollection(Request.Form).ToValueProvider();
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good idea, because you're adding code to facilitate tests into production code. It also gets executed on every request, and it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Why not just use the "ValueProvider = ..." line in the setup of your controlller in your unit tests.

Answer (score 15):

You should add this code:

```
 FormCollection formValues = new FormCollection() 
        {
            { "Test", "test" },
            { "FirstName", "TestName" } 
        };
        rootController.ValueProvider = formValues.ToValueProvider();
```

I have the same problem and this code helps me.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a change in implementation of `System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider` that is hitting a value in `ControllerContext` that is null.

You may need to mock an additional value in `ControllerContext`.

At least that's where I'd look first.

EDIT

Yeah, looks like it's doing a null check on `controllerContext`.

```
public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    if (controllerContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
    }
    object deserializedObject = GetDeserializedObject(controllerContext);
    if (deserializedObject == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    Dictionary<string, object> backingStore = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    AddToBackingStore(backingStore, string.Empty, deserializedObject);
    return new DictionaryValueProvider<object>(backingStore, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

From the stacktrace we can see that `TryUpdateModel[TModel](TModel model, String prefix)`.  Using reflector, it is accessing the `ControllerBase` `ValueProvider` property.  This in turn calls  `ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext)` with the current Controllers `ControllerContext` property.

You should just be able to create a new `ControllerContext` instance and set the controller's property accordingly...

```
[TestMethod]
public void EditTest
{
    var controller = new Controller();         
    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext();

    controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

    controller.Edit(...);       
}
```

Some additional mocking may be required to get it to fully function though.  Some info on how to fully mock ControllerContext: [Mocking Asp.net-mvc Controller Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640/mocking-asp-net-mvc-controller-context)

Comment: I guesst almost as much, but which value exactly do I need to mock? And how can I do this? This seems to be a pretty common scenario...

Comment: A common scenario for brand new code isn't that common. ;)  Why don't you include your current mocks and then we could point out likely additions.  Are you mocking the header?

Comment: Yeah doesn't look like the MVC3 source is available yet... that could make things bit more challenging. I'll load up Reflector and see what I can find.

Comment: If you're unit testing a method which calls UpdateModel, you should set the Controller.ValueProvider property manually before running the test.  I'd recommend setting it to an instance of SimpleValueProvider, which is just a fancy NameValueCollection.

Comment: I had to add both a ValueProvider and a ControllerContext