# ASP.NET MVC - Ready to use ControllerContext mock

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, mocking, controller

I studied several samples, including one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640/mocking-asp-net-mvc-controller-context), and basically all I need to know is whether there is something new in the field.

The greatest thing would be having some ready-to-use thoroughly tested by multiple real-life uses class / method that will return me the mock of ControllerContext for unit testing ASP.NET MVC controllers. One more desirable feature is not having to worry about what to mock, what not to mock - I just want a fully functional context. Maybe, I will not need 90% of its functionality, but that's ok. Is there something that sweet?

The solution may use some Mock framework, but it is not necessary - I just need the result out from black box. If this box is not actually black, that's better, of course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would recommend you [MVCContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper). It will make your controller unit tests very elegant and you shouldn't worry about mocking the context.

Comment: This looks like what I need. I'll test it a bit and if it is really that good, I'll accept the answer. Thanks!