# How to mock HttpContext (ControllerContext) in Moq framework, and have session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq, httpcontext

I want to test my MVC application, and I want to mock HttpContext. I'm using **Moq** framework, and here is what I've done to mock HttpContext:

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    MyUser myUser = new MyUser();
    myUser.Id = 1;
    myUser.Name = "AutomatedUITestUser";

    var fakeHttpSessionState = 
                         new FakeHttpSessionState(new SessionStateItemCollection());
    fakeHttpSessionState.Add("__CurrentUser__", myUser);

    ControllerContext mockControllerContext = Mock.Of<ControllerContext>(ctx =>
        ctx.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name == myUser.Name &&
        ctx.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true &&
        ctx.HttpContext.Session == fakeHttpSessionState &&
        ctx.HttpContext.Request.AcceptTypes == 
                       new string[]{ "MyFormsAuthentication" } &&
        ctx.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated == true &&
        ctx.HttpContext.Request.Url == new Uri("http://moqthis.com") &&
        ctx.HttpContext.Response.ContentType == "application/xml");

    _controller = new SomeController();
     _controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext; //this line is not working
    //when I see _controller.ControllerContext in watch, it get's me 
    //_controller.ControllerContext threw an exception of type System.ArgumentException
}

[Test]
public void Test_ControllerCanDoSomething()
{
    // testing an action of the controller
    // The problem is, here, System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null
}
```

Because my application uses **Session** to hold user data and authentication info in almost every action method, thus I need to set `HttpContext` and inside it I need to set `Session` and put `__CurrentUser__` inside session, so that action methods would have access to faked logged in user.

However, `HttpContext` is not set and it's null. I've searched a lot and I couldn't find my answer. 
What might be wrong?

**Update:**
I also test below line, and get same result

```
_controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(
                       mockControllerContext.HttpContext, new RouteData(), _controller);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mock the HttpContext in ASP.NET MVC using Moq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq)

Comment: Microsoft recommends using HttpContextWrapper in your code so that unit testing will be easier later on.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextwrapper(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks @MikeCheel but my question is different, I dont set HttpContext instead of ControllerContext, my problem is I can't set ControllerContext ! can anyone answer my qiestion ?

Comment: You can create a ControllerContext and pass in a HttpContextBase into its constructor. Also, the HttpContext on the ControllerContext is an HttpContextBAse and so you should be able to use the HttpContextWrapper.

Comment: I also test below line, and get same result
_controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockControllerContext.HttpContext, new RouteData(), _controller);

Comment: Have you tried enabling .net source code stepping in visual studio to see where the exception is thrown it might give you some more hints?

Answer (score 3):

Judging by this answer: [Mocking Asp.net-mvc Controller Context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32672/141022)

It looks like you need to mock the Request itself, as well as the properties of the request object.

e.g.

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
```

etc (the full code is in the linked answer).

Comment: How about mocking System.Web.HttpRequest (Form) in WebApi?

Comment: Hi @Dave you're better off asking as a separate question if you haven't already.