# Creating a Mock for HTTPMethods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nsubstitute

In my controller I have a line of code like this

```
string method = HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;
```

and based on if it is a `GET` or `POST`, method is doing different things that I want test.  But first I should be able to mock this.  We are using **NSubstitute**.

I did some research and the closest I found was this answer but none of them are using **NSubstitue**.

[Mocking Asp.net-mvc Controller Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640/mocking-asp-net-mvc-controller-context)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating mocks and configuring return values is described in the [NSubstitute documentation](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/).

So we can create a mock `IFoo` using:

```
var foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
```

We can configure a member to return a specific value using `Returns`:

```
// Make HttpMethod property return "GET"
foo.HttpMethod.Returns("GET");

// Make someOtherMock.GetFoo() return foo 
someOtherMock.GetFoo().Returns(foo);
```

And we can inject a mocked value into another class:

```
var x = new Context(foo, ... );
```

I think that's everything required to port the [linked code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32640/906)<sup>1</sup>. If you need any more info please comment and I'll update the answer.

---

<sup>1</sup> *I'm avoiding posting the full translation as it probably varies for different MVC versions. Hopefully this answer will help you port any snippet you need.*